# In Application of Taylor Polynomials section in Stewart Calculus 3rd, 7^(8/3) > 179?

Tags: calculus

I am going over the very old edition of Stewart's "Calculus" 3rd edition, and found this innocent inequality approximation $7^{8/3} > 179$ in the section of Application of Taylor Polynomials (10.12). I don't think the particular material to be learned matter here. In fact, $7^{8/3} = 179.3059$. I am wondering if I am missing some scheme to approximation this type of calculation.

Comment: Doing this with Taylor series seems inconvenient (though perfectly possible).  Easy enough to check that $7^8>179^3$ of course.

Comment: Ah, that's kind of reasonable. The page innocuously puts the inequality as if it looks obvious. Is it obvious that $7^{8}$ should be somewhere around $180^{3}$ for any ways? I can only see it should be between $7^{8/4}$ and $8^{8/3}$. Between 49 and 256 is not tight enough to guess 179 with a few trials.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that this was obvious, no.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series aren't that bad. We use the binomial series
$$(8+t)^{\frac 83}=256\left(1+\frac{t}{8}\right)^{\frac83} = 256\left(1+\frac83\cdot\frac t8+\frac{8\cdot 5}{3^2\cdot 2}\cdot\frac{t^2}{64}+\frac{8\cdot 5\cdot 2}{3^3\cdot 6}\cdot\frac{t^3}{512}+\cdots\right)$$
Evaluating at $t=-1$, the four terms I've written out come to $256$, $-\frac{256}{3}=-85-\frac13$, $\frac{80}{9}=9-\frac19$, and $-\frac{20}{81}$. Adding them, I get $256-85+9-\frac13-\frac19-\frac{20}{81}=180-\frac{56}{81}>179$.

All right, we need an estimate for the tail as well. The fourth derivative is (for $-1\le t\le 0$)
$$256\cdot\frac{8\cdot 5\cdot 2\cdot -1}{3^4\cdot 8^4}\left(1+\frac t8\right)^{-\frac43}=\frac{-10}{2\cdot 81}\left(1+\frac t8\right)^{-\frac43} < \frac{1}{16}\cdot \frac43$$
That inequality is really about absolute values, estimating $81>80$ and $\left(\frac87\right)^{\frac43}<\left(\frac87\right)^2<\frac86$. The error in our third degree polynomial is $\frac{f^{(4)}(c)}{24}$ for some $c$, or less than $\frac1{12\cdot 24}=\frac1{288}$. Subtract that from $179+\frac{25}{81}$, and it's still greater than $179$. Proved.

No calculating aids were used here - just pencil and paper.

Comment: This is an alternating series, so the 5th term bounds the error.

Comment: No, it's not alternating. From the $x^3$ term on, the terms are all the same sign.

Comment: 'K.  You win....this time....